# Firebase with angular odd solution

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I'm trying to use firebase with angular.
I've stuck at one point when my application said firebase.initializeApp is not a function.

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
```

(it was this before: `import * as firebase from "firebase";` )

So I've checked the firebase variable and inside the object there wasn't any initializeApp only another "firebase" object and a few other property.
in the firebase object there was finally the initializeApp.
So my solution was:

```
firebase.firebase.initializeApp({...});
```

I have tried other solutions and they didn't work.
I've declared these variables so I can use firebase as normally I wanted:

```
const FIREBASE_APP = require("firebase");
const FIREBASE = FIREBASE_APP.firebase;
```

Does anyone know a better solution for it?
Maybe there is some problem with the mapping in my config file?
(I can provide my system.config.js)

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts, use AngularFireModule from angularfire2

```
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
...
imports: {
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp({...}),
}
```

Comment: I've got this error: GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/firebase/app.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: have you run `npm i --save firebase angularfire2` ?